# How to select first 5 webelements and iterate?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

List nines=driver.findElements(By.xpath(("//select[contains(@id,'ddlIN_HH')]")));

```
   for(WebElement nine : nines)

   { Select s= new Select(nine);

   s.selectByValue("09");

   }
```

Comment: You can select by index instead and then loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select first 5 elements directly using xpath function position()
so your new xpath would be

```
List nines=driver.findElements(By.xpath(("//select[contains(@id,'ddlIN_HH')]")[position() < 6]));
```